# CSS Transform: scaleX not working in Safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, transform, scale

I have this shark that swims on my site. http://jaredshurtliff.com/ It goes back and forth using the CSS Transform: scaleX property. It's supposed to go to one side, turn around, go to the other side, turn around, etc. It works in every single browser except Safari. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="shark">
        <div id="shark_body"></div>
        <div id="shark_fin"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#shark {
width: 500px;
height: 220px;
position: absolute;
top: 75%;
left: 20%;
padding: 0;

animation-name:swim;
animation-duration:50s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;

-moz-animation-name:swim;
-moz-animation-duration:50s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

-webkit-animation-name:swim;
-webkit-animation-duration:50s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
```

}

And here's the animation (I'll just display the -webkit- portion:

```
@-webkit-keyframes swim{
from{
    left: 20%;
}
20%{
    left:1%;
    transform:scaleX(1);
}
20.5%{
    transform:scaleX(-1);
    left:0%;
}
21%{
    left: 5%;
}
50%{
    left: 55%;
    transform:scaleX(-1);
}
50.5%{
    transform:scaleX(1);
    left: 58%;
}
51%{
    left: 53%;
}
70%{
    left: 1%;
    transform:scaleX(1);
}
70.5%{
    transform:scaleX(-1);
    left:0%;
}
71%{
    left: 5%;
}
82%{
    left: 55%;
    transform:scaleX(-1);
}
82.5%{
    transform:scaleX(1);
    left: 58%;
}
83%{
    left: 53%;
}
to{
    left:20%;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Nice idea, but that didn't do it. I basically used the swim animation from [link]http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-animated-fish-tank which works just fine in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

i think you forgot to add prefix for `webkit` and other browsers in `@keyframes`

```
    -webkit-transform:scaleX(1);
    -moz-transform:scaleX(1);
    -ms-transform:scaleX(1);
    -o-transform:scaleX(1);
    transform:scaleX(1);
```